# Diagonally Dominant Matrix Preserved after Gaussian Elimination (with a modification)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Prove or disprove: If a matrix has the property $0 \neq |a_{ii}| \geq \sum_{\substack{j=1 \\ j \neq i}} |a_{ij}| $ then Gaussian Elimination (without pivoting) will preserve this property.**

I assume this to be true since I have seen other theorems state that "Gaussian elimination without pivoting preserves the diagonal dominance of a matrix" without much other qualification. I am not sure how the inequality to 0 would change this. However, most of those used the strong inequality not the weak, so perhaps that would change things as well. Could someone help me with a proof to verify this? Else provide a counterexample?

I have been trying to come up with one to no avail. I would assume showing that the first row iteration of Gaussian preserves the condition would mostly complete the proof so I have been trying to come at it with that in mind.

Comment: What is *pivoting* exactly?

Comment: After each iteration, switching the rows or columns such that the largest element is on the diagonal for the next set of row elimination in Gaussian.

Comment: I am a little confused as to why the answer that was here (while somewhat incorrect) went away?

Comment: Answers owners have the option (to some extent) to delete their answers. I chose to delete mine.

Answer (score 1):

I answered this question in another post. Here it is:

We only need to show that after eliminating $a_{2,1}$, diagonal dominance is preserved, i.e.,
$$
\left|a_{2,2}-a_{1,2}{a_{2,1}\over a_{1,1}}\right|\ge\sum_{i=3}^n\left|a_{2,i}-a_{1,i}{a_{2,1}\over a_{1,1}}\right|,
$$
which is equivalent to 
$$
|a_{2,2}a_{1,1}-a_{1,2}a_{2,1}|\ge\sum_{i=3}^n|a_{2,i}a_{1,1}-a_{1,i}a_{2,1}|.
$$
But this is true:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=3}^n|a_{2,i}a_{1,1}-a_{1,i}a_{2,1}|&\le& 
|a_{1,1}|\sum_{i=3}^n|a_{2,i}|+|a_{2,1}|\sum_{i=3}^n|a_{1,i}| \\
&\le& |a_{1,1}|(|a_{2,2}|-|a_{2,1}|)+|a_{2,1}|(|a_{1,1}|-|a_{1,2}|) \\
&=&|a_{1,1}||a_{2,2}|-|a_{2,1}||a_{1,2}|\\
&\le& |a_{1,1}a_{2,2}-a_{2,1}a_{1,2}|
\end{eqnarray*}